# How do I care for these three succulents?

Tags: houseplants, plant-care, succulents

I was given a present of three succulents in a glass greenhouse...

[image]

As you can see, they are planted in some sort of moss, possibly sphagnum, but not sure.

Now I'm no plant expert at all, but my understanding is that succulents in general need very dry conditions, which is why you get them in hot dry countries. These three are growing in moss, which will retain a lot of water, and are in a closed glass box (which is now slightly open, the the middle plant has a leaf that has grown towards the camera, pushing the hinged door open a little) which will retain moisture.

What do I do? I've had them for about a month now, and haven't watered at all. They are sitting on a west-facing window, where they get a lot of light, and are above a radiator, so are generally at a comfortable temperature.

Any advice would be greatly welcome as I'd like to keep them healthy. In case it makes any difference, I live in north-west England.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're on the right track with your desert plants, like [Haworthia](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QkRUPXnWsbU).

1. Get them out of the presentation box and use it for moisture lovers.
2. Southern window is best for max sun. Inside, your outside zone doesn't matter much, but summer them outdoors after frost ends - April 10 in Manchester.
3. Watering once a month is too stingey. Modest watering weekly is better for the Winter.
4. Look inside the moss for a hidden sandy medium. If not, water sparingly as the sheet moss (not sphagnum) holds moisture, though it does remain airy. Do not repot until you see new growth, to allow for your babies literally to acclimate.

The three succulents seem to be 1-Pachyphytum 'Moon Silver', 2-Pachyphytum Compactum (or Pachyveria Glauca) 'Little Jewel', and 3-Tiger Haworthia (though it screams Aloe to me).

Comment: Thanks for the very helpful reply. I'll move them into open pots with a more suitable medium. Do you have suggestions? By the way, the medium is moss all the way down, no sand, nothing else, just moss moss and more moss!

Comment: Ooh forgot - Thanks also for identifying the Haworthia. As far as I can see from a search, that identifies the one on the right. Any idea what the left and middle ones are? Be helpful to know so I can search for specific care instructions. Thanks again